# Set database based on authenticated user LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.6 and I would like to set the default database based on the authenticated user

like when `user1` logged the `DB1` set as default and like so with `user2` set the databse to `DB2`

any suggest or other ways to make it?

thanks

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18975500/laravel-change-the-default-database-connection-globally

Comment: See how you can handle multiple databases here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-database-in-laravel

Answer (score 2):

First you can update the connection configuration details with the relevant values based on your user (I'm assuming here that the default connection name is `mysql`):

```
// This will overwrite only the values you need updated so you don't have
// to add all of the configuration keys like 'driver', 'charset', etc
config()->set('database.connections.mysql', array_merge(config('database.connections.mysql'), [
    'database' => 'new_database',
    'username' => 'new_username',
    'password' => 'new_password',
]));
```

Then you just need to reconnect to the database and it will use the new configuration:

```
\DB::reconnect('mysql');
```

All this code would probably be best placed in a middleware, so it runs automatically on each request.

Comment: Right, that what I'm looking for, set all the code in a middleware and make the middleware global

Answer (score 1):

using Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

you could do

```
 if(Auth::user()->type == 1){
      $users = DB::connection('DB1 ')->select(...);
 }else{
      $users = DB::connection('user2 ')->select(...);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it will be great if I use multiple databases with different tables