# How to update database name and set persistent connect for entire session laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have secondary connection that comes dynamically and here is it's code

```
 'userdb' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => DYNAMIC_DATABASE_NAME,
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false,
        ],
```

So, once use logged in I want to update update this database dynamically and reconnect to this **userdb**.

I have used following code but this is not giving persistent DB connection I have to this this everytime manually.
Any suggestions ?

```
DB::purge('userdb');
config(['database.connections.userdb.database' => 'test']);
DB::reconnect('userdb');
DB::connection('userdb');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: connect to databases dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085131/laravel-connect-to-databases-dynamically)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - change the default database connection globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18975500/laravel-change-the-default-database-connection-globally)

Comment: But the issue is every time I have to write code for reconnect database 'userdb'

Comment: It's only temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

1.first set database name

```
\Config::set('database.connections.userdb.database','test');
```

2.after set database name  you need to purge the DB cache

```
\DB::purge('userdb');
```

3.set default connection after u purge db cache

```
\DB::setDefaultConnection('userdb');
```

Comment: I am getting this error "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Config' not found"

Comment: I already know this solution and I also written in my question Please check my question. The issue is when I change my page connection got reverted to old one.

Comment: @RonakChauhan  pl join this group  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193251/dynamic-connection